# Combining text files into a data frame in R with time windows

Tags: performance, beginner, datetime, r

I have a very slow function with multiple for loops to read in the following text with the line's data type (`Followball` or `DRT`), as well as a `time`, target position, and `cursor position` for the `Followball` lines:

```
FollowBall,1173,897.3,894.7
FollowBall,1205,897.1,893.9
FollowBall,1236,896.9,893.6
FollowBall,1267,896.7,893.3
FollowBall,1298,896.5,893.2
DRT,1314,583794, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, miss
FollowBall,1330,896.3,893.1
FollowBall,1361,896.0,893.1
FollowBall,1392,895.8,893.0
FollowBall,1423,895.6,892.9
```

I read in these files for part `a` and `b` with filenames like `RemoteChoice_001a_ST.txt`,`RemoteChoice_001b_ST.txt`. There are 40-ish files. In this file there are `DRT` lines with `mode` (a factor with 4 levels) at the 4th position and `load` (a factor with 2 levels) at the 5th position on the line. Right now I'm making a `data.frame` like the one below and comparing all of the `Followball` lines to see if they're in the time windows:

```
   mode load     beg_time     end_time
1     0    0 1.470616e+12 1.470616e+12
2     0    1 1.470616e+12 1.470616e+12
3     2    1 1.470616e+12 1.470616e+12
4     1    1 1.470616e+12 1.470617e+12
5     1    0 1.470617e+12 1.470618e+12
6     2    0 1.470618e+12 1.470618e+12
7     2    1 1.470618e+12 1.470618e+12
8     3    0 1.470618e+12 1.470619e+12
9     3    1 1.470619e+12 1.470619e+12
10    0    1 1.470619e+12 1.470619e+12
11    0    0 1.470619e+12 1.470619e+12
```

This function currently takes 30 minutes to run:

```
   ExtractSteering<- function(topdir) {
  total = Sys.time()
  dirs <- list.dirs(path = topdir, full.names = TRUE) #get directories
  files <- list.files(path=dirs, pattern="*.txt", full.names=T, recursive=F) #get files
  subids1 <- regmatches(files, regexpr("0\\d*.", files)) #get subject ids
  subids <- substr(subids1, 2,3) #get just the id number
  day <- substr(subids1, 4,4) #get conditions

  for (j in 1:length(files)) { #For every file, open it and read the lines
    linesall <- readLines(files[j]) #save all the lines to a vector
    time_df <- data.frame() #make an empty data.frame to be filled by time windows
    drtmatch <- regexpr("^D.*", linesall) #Get all DRT lines
    drts <- regmatches(linesall, drtmatch) #Save all DRT lines
    drtdat <- cSplit(data.frame(drts),"drts",",") #Make a data.frame with lines
    windows <- dplyr::select(drtdat, time = drts_02, mode = drts_04, load = drts_05) #label columns
    for (i in seq_along(windows$mode)) { #for the 902 lines of windows mode
      if (windows$mode[i] != lag(windows$mode, default = 4)[i] | #see if mode changes
          windows$load[i] != lag(windows$load, default = 4)[i]) { #see if load changes
        rows <- c(windows$mode[i],windows$load[i],windows$time[i]) #save out the change point with a time
        time_df <- rbind(time_df, rows) #fill the empty data.frame with the mode, load, and timestamp
      }
    }
    colName <- c("mode","load","time") #name the columns
    time_windows <- time_df %>% #get a beginning time and end time on the same row
      setNames(colName) %>% #column names
      mutate(beg_time = time, end_time = lead(time, default = 100000000000)) %>% #same row
      select(-time) #get rid of old time
    matches <- regexpr("^Follow.*$", linesall) #Get all Followball lines
    follows <- regmatches(linesall, matches) #save Followball lines
    dat <- cSplit(data.frame(follows),"follows", ",") #make data.frame
    dat <- dplyr::select(dat, time = follows_2, ballpos = follows_3, cursorpos = follows_4) %>%
      mutate(deviation = abs(ballpos - cursorpos)) %>% #labels, create deviation
      filter(deviation < 100) %>% #get rid of big deviations
      arrange(time) #arrange by timestamp
    dat$time <- as.numeric(as.character(dat$time)) #make sure time is numeric
    dat <- dat[seq(10, nrow(dat), 10), ] #sample every 10 because it takes so damn long
    df_part <- data.frame() #empty data.frame
    tic <- Sys.time() #Figure out why it's taking so long
    for(row in seq_along(time_windows$mode)) { #go back into mode
      for(i in seq_along(dat$time)) { #go back into time
        if(dat$time[i] > time_windows$beg_time[row] & dat$time[i] < time_windows$end_time[row]) { #check if the time is in the window
          rows <- c(time_windows$mode[row], time_windows$load[row],dat$deviation[i]) #make a row with mode, load, and deviation
          df_part <- rbind(df_part, rows) #add to empty dataframe
        }
      }
      print(Sys.time() - tic) #Figure out why it's taking so long
    }
    df_full <-  df_part %>% #Rename stuff
      `colnames<-`(c("mode", "load", "deviation")) #%>%

    infile <- df_full #Don't save over things
    infile$subid <- as.factor(subids[j]) #Add subid from file name
    infile$day <- as.factor(day[j]) #Add day from file name

    if(!exists("drt.data")) {
      drt.data <- infile #Create ouput data.frame
    }
    else {
      drt.data <- rbind(drt.data,infile) #Append to output dataframe
    }
    cat("Finished Processing Participant: ", subids[j],day[j],"Total time:", Sys.time() - total) #get feedback
  }
    return(drt.data) #Return full data.frame
}
```

Here is my current sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] tcltk     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lme4_1.1-13           Matrix_1.2-10         papaja_0.1.0.9492     bindrcpp_0.2         
 [5] dplyr_0.7.2           purrr_0.2.3           readr_1.1.1           tidyr_0.6.3          
 [9] tibble_1.3.3          tidyverse_1.1.1       splitstackshape_1.4.2 data.table_1.10.4    
[13] ggplot2_2.2.1         plyr_1.8.4            multcomp_1.4-6        TH.data_1.0-8        
[17] MASS_7.3-47           survival_2.41-3       mvtnorm_1.0-6         car_2.1-5            
[21] forcats_0.2.0         stringr_1.2.0
```

`head()` of output:

```
  mode load deviation subid day
1    0    0 0.7341692    01   a
2    0    0 0.6613210    01   a
3    0    0 0.9878947    01   a
4    0    0 0.8304713    01   a
5    0    0 0.9878947    01   a
6    0    0 1.0841968    01   a
```

Is there any other information I can add to receive help with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your code run faster, it is important to know (a) which parts are slow and (b) which parts can be easily improved and how. Regarding (a), I suspect the loops across the rows, (e.g., `for (i in seq_along(windows$mode))`) make your code slow. Regarding (b), those loops should probably be avoided, maybe using a `dplyr::filter()` call.

Try to identify the slow parts of your code yourself, for example, using the [**profvis** package](https://github.com/rstudio/profvis) (see also [Adavanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html)):

```
library(profvis)
profvis({
    ExtractSteering()
})
```

Of course, you should run `ExtractSteering()` on only one (or a few) TXT files to reduce computation time.

If the for loops indeed are the slow parts, I would propose that you give more details about those few lines at best with a running MWE so that we can help you---if necessary---to improve that part.

Moreover, wouldn't it be easier, safer, and faster to replace `readLines(files[j])` with, for example, `readr::read_csv(files[j])`?

Comment: Good advice about profiling. I bet it will show the culprit is the repeated use of the `x <- rbind(x, ...)` construct inside `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll be looking through these potential problems and maybe posting the updated function.